# Expression Language support in Golang

Tags: postgresql, go, configuration, el

I am trying to implement a functionality that lets users try out configurations in run rime.

Basically, there are some preexisting configurations in DB, but users can make some tweaks on top of those and see results.

This component is written in Golang. One approach i am thinking is about using expression language support. I found some open source packages like https://github.com/araddon/qlbridge

But there are almost negligible number of sample programs / tutorials that demo how to use expression language along with PostgresQL.

Has any one used and attempted such thing? Any suggestions are welcome. Thank you for your time!

Comment: what do you want to configure?

Comment: I want to configure run time rules (and have a capability to evaluate those runtime). If the configurations are okay for requirements, i want to store those for future computations.

Comment: Hm, i'm sorry i don't know what you mean by "expression language". You are not talking about writing or storing SQL queries, right?

Comment: No problem. Thanks for asking. I am talking about storing expressions that can be operated on top of existing DB contents. These expressions would be stored only if they are satisfying certain criteria. To identify whether the expression satisfies certain criteria, i need some kind of expression language evaluator that works on top of postgresql DB contents (lets say, we get those details in some struct).

Comment: I'm not sure this is quite for your use-case given that you allow users to interact with it. For a project where I needed to give an extra dynamic boost, I found this library which will evaluate javascript in go. My usage was purely internal though, so I wasn't much concerned with the possible safety issues with executing raw javascript. I guess it depends on what exactly you are letting them do and how it affects your application. https://github.com/robertkrimen/otto

Answer (score 3):

Try https://github.com/antonmedv/expr – is an engine that can evaluate expressions.

It can handle expressions like this:

```
user.Group in ["good_customers", "collaborator"]

len(article.Comments) > 100 and article.Category not in ["misc"]

product.Stock < 15

all(Tickets, {.Price >0})
```

And also has static type checker and user-friendly error messages

```
error: unclosed "("
 | (boo + bar]
 | ----------^
```